# Run Chromium inside container: libGl error

Tags: docker, chromium

I'm trying to run Chromium inside docker container.
Here's the output I get:

```
Created new window in existing browser session.
libGL error: failed to open drm device: No such file or directory
libGL error: failed to load driver: vmwgfx
```

I've searched a lot on the internet about this issue but cannot find anything clear. Do you have any suggestions on how can I solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found a Git issue that suggested the issue might be that you need to enable hardware acceleration for your docker container. See if this guide helps: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration

Comment: Maybe not related to your question but you could be interested in [headless-chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

Answer (score 7):

As Mark Wragg wrote in a comment; [this guide from wiki.ros.org is pretty good](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration)

It seems like you're missing the vmwgfx GL drivers, at [mesa3d.org](https://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html) you can see how to install them.

Myself ran into this issue after all drivers was installed, but then I found out that I also need to mount the graphic card to the docker container. For Intel cards that's made with

```
docker run --device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri ...
```

For other graphic cards I recommend the guide from [wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration)

Comment: or simply `docker run --device=/dev/dri`

Answer (score -3):

If it's for isolation, you can achieve something practically similar by running as may unrelated instances of Chromium as you like with the --user-data-dir= option:

```
 chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome1
```

Or

```
 chromium-browser --user-data-dir=`mktemp` &
 chromium-browser --user-data-dir=`mktemp` &
 chromium-browser --user-data-dir=`mktemp` &
```

The additional isolation that docker brings is thin compared to the security and isolation baked into Chrome.